# Auto generate objects Id mongo db c#

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, identity, mongodb-.net-driver

I learn mongodb with C#, I want to create a record with a list of entities but the child entities didn't generate his object id.

Here's my code:

```
public class Curso
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("descripcion")]
    public string descripcion { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("horas")]
    public int horas { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("alumnos")]
    public IEnumerable<Alumno> alumnos { get; set; }

    public Curso()
    {

    }
}
```

Alumno entity:

```
public class Alumno
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("age")]
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

I insert a new course, the auto generate id Curso is worked but the Alumno id didn't generate and is set to `"000000000000000000000000"` instead.

```
    public Curso create(Curso curso)
    {
        db.GetCollection<Curso>("curso").Save(curso);
        return curso;
    }
```

RESULT:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a766ec765583a0f90bc0edf"), "descripcion" : "JAVA + JPA", "horas" : 200, "alumnos" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), "name" : "Catalina Castillo", "age" : 22 }, { "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), "name" : "Marcia Pardo", "age" : 45 }, { "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), "name" : "Will Smith", "age" : 24 } ] }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each MongoDB document should have `_id` field with unique value. That's why, when you pass `Curso` document with zero `_id`, MongoDB generates it for you.

However that't not the case for embedded documents. For MongoDB, `_id` field in embedded document is just an ordinary field as `age` or `name`. That's why MongDB does not bother itself for filling `_id` of embedded documents and saves them as you pass, i.e. zero-filled.

So you should generate values for `Alumno._id` by yourself. You could do it either in `Alumno` constructor or before inserting document in the database:

```
public class Alumno
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("age")]
    public int age { get; set; }

    public Alumno()
    {
        _id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also declare your property with the following attribute:

```
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(ObjectIdGenerator))]
public ObjectId? _id { get; set; }
```

This will generate an id.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the Id field in your code, but don't want to set it yourself, then you could use BsonRepresentation and string Id as well. If your Id field is not ObjectId and not on Id, you can use `[BsonId]`.

```cs
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was surprising that the _id representation in the mongodb database is different depending on if the id/Id/_id field is of type `string` or `ObjectId`.

Example type string id:
[image: Example type string id]

Example type ObjectId:
[image: Example type ObjectId]

Also when json-serializing an object with id of type `ObjectId` the output is not very usable to send to the browser.
Example serialization result:

```json
{
  "id": {
    "Timestamp": 1692982711,
    "Machine": 13655676,
    "Pid": -26385,
    "Increment": 8598747,
    "CreationTime": "2023-08-25T16:58:31Z"
  },
  "name": "test2"
}
```

Here the code to reproduce the results:

```cs
record TestDoc1(string id, string name = "test1");
record TestDoc2(ObjectId id, string name = "test2");

[Fact]
public async Task MongoDbTest()
{
    var client = new MongoClient(_connectionUri);
    var testDB = client.GetDatabase($"testDB");
    var testCollection1 = testDB.GetCollection<TestDoc1>("testCollection1");
    var testCollection2 = testDB.GetCollection<TestDoc2>("testCollection2");
    
    var objectId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    var docWithStringId = new TestDoc1(objectId.ToString());
    var docWithObjectId = new TestDoc2(objectId);
    var docWithObjectIdAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(docWithObjectId, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
    Console.WriteLine(docWithObjectIdAsJson);
    await testCollection1.InsertOneAsync(docWithStringId, null);
    await testCollection2.InsertOneAsync(docWithObjectId, null);
}
```